# Force browser to download a file to a spefic location using javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, download, location

Is there any way in which the web browser can be forced to download a file to a specific location (programmatically )in the client system ?

The scripting language used in javascript.

Comment: No you cant. That would be fun... You can prompt the user if he wants to download a file, but you cant force it.

Comment: @adeneo can you post that as an answer so I can vote for it?